# How do I format document.on when using the jQuery mask method?

Tags: jquery

I have the flowing jQuery code that establishes an input mask:

```
$("#text_field").mask("~~~~?~~~~",{placeholder:""});
```

How do I translate this into a document.on statement?
This is as far as I've gotten:

```
$(document).on('mask', '#text_field', function() {};
```

Basically, I don't know how to format the mask details part: 
"~~~~?~~~~",{placeholder:""}

Thanks

Comment: jQuery has no mask method. What plugin are you using?

Comment: You are confusing event delegation with initializing a plugin. You can't initialize a plugin on elements that don't exist yet. If you are loading them with ajax do the initialization in ajax callbacks